# What is the runtime performance of get() method in TreeMap & HashMap with size of n

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, big-o, treemap

Recently a interview question make me feel uncertainty.

for get() method in both TreeMap and HashMap, what is its performace?

a)
Average: constant(independent of n)
Worst: constant(independent of n)

b)
Average: constant(independent of n)
Worst: proportional to log(n)

c)
Average: constant(independent of n)
Worst: proportional to (n)

d)
Average: proportional to log(n)
Worst: proportional to (n)

Which is correct?

Comment: by the way, it's in Java

Answer (score 8):

[`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

> This implementation provides constant-time performance for the basic
>   operations (get and put), assuming the hash function disperses the
>   elements properly among the buckets.

However note that modifying the *load factor* (default value = `0.75`) might have some effect on the cost of some operations in `HashMap`.

> As a general rule, the default load factor (.75) offers a good
>   tradeoff between time and space costs. Higher values decrease the
>   space overhead but increase the lookup cost (reflected in most of the
>   operations of the HashMap class, including get and put).

A different value of *load factor* can be enforced by using one of the overloaded constructors.

[`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)

> This implementation provides guaranteed log(n) time cost for the
>   containsKey, get, put and remove operations.

Comment: So @user838204 is right to be confused in the case of (the guaranteed reasonably balanced) `TreeMap`.

Comment: Yes the worst is `log(n)` for a `TreeMap`. None of the choices suggests it.

Comment: Sorry to make you confused. So the answer for HashMap is A and the answer for TreeMap is:  Average: proportional to log(n) Worst: proportional to log(n)??

Answer (score 0):

The answer is d

The Tree map is implemeneted a red black tree and hence the average case of is o(log n)

Hashmap takes o(n) in the worst case

Comment: From the answer above, does HashMap take <b>constant-time</b> for worst case?

Comment: I would think it depends on Hash function. In Java 8, the values are stored as BST, so it makes it roughly worst case O(logn), and pre Java 8 it was linked List with worst case as O(n)